# Declaring union types with nil in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang, union-types

I've been following the official documentation of [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/union_types.html) but I couldn't find any details on this. The regular syntax when declaring a union type is `String | Int32`. However, I've noticed a difference regarding the `Nil` type.

The regular way of declaring the union still works:

```
def foo(id : String | Nil)
end

# Overloads are:
#  - foo(id : String | Nil)
```

However I've also seen a shortened syntax which I couldn't find any documentation for:

```
def foo(id : String?)
end

# Overloads are:
#  - foo(id : String | ::Nil)
```

The result is almost exactly the same except `Nil` if prefixed with 2 colons. My guess that this is something related to the global scope of `Nil` as I've seen a similar syntax in other languages.

1. Is `String | Nil` and `String?` the same thing, and when should you use one vs the other?
2. What's the meaning of 2 colons in the type signature (e.g. `::Nil`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. yes, they're exactly the same, people typically use the `Foo?` version as it's shorter.
2. `::Nil` means "the class Nil at the root namespace". This means that if you define a different `Nil` class in a different namespace, `::Nil` always refers to the nil in the stdlib.

Comment: So in the 1nd case `Nil` isn't prefixed because the type was explicitly specified (no way of class name conflict)? I expected as much, just needed a confirmation.

Comment: Exactly. When the compiler expands the `?` suffix, it replaces it with `| ::Nil` to specifically target `Nil` at global scope and avoid potential naming clashes.